# Matlab script rendering black as purple in output .eps

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a MATLAB script I use to render data (in this case a timeline of lots of rectangles) and everything works fine in the MATLAB Figure viewer. However for some reason when I output the files as a .eps using print, some of the black (text and boxes in the plot) turns purple.

```
    static = importdata( 'output.out');
    static(:,3) = ( static(:,3) - static(:,2) ) * tpms;
    start = min( static(:,2) );
    static(:,2) = ( static(:,2) - start ) * tpms;
    ms_max = max(static(:,2)) - min(static(:,2))
    ms_max = ms_max + 0.1 * ms_max;
    %ms_max = max(static(:,2)) - min(static(:,2));
    static_corner = static( static(:,1)==0 , : );
    static_row = static( static(:,1)==1 , : );
    static_column = static( static(:,1)==2 , : );
    static_split = static( static(:,1) == 3, :);
    %static_rest = static( static(:,1)==3 , : );
    static_unload = static( static(:,1)==-101 , : );
    static_load = static( static(:,1)==-100 , : );
    static_ghost = static(static(:,1)==-102,:);

    % Init the plot
    clf;
    subplot('position',[ 0.05 , 0.1 , 0.9 , 0.8 ]);
    hold on;

    % Plot the selfs in RED
    for k=1:size(static_corner,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_corner(k,2) , static_corner(k,4)+0.5 , static_corner(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0.8 0 0 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 1 0 0 ] );
    end
    arrays = 0.0;
    for k=1:size(static_corner,1)
        arrays = arrays + static_corner(k,3);
    end
    arrays/size(static_corner,1)


    % Plot the pairs in GREEN
    for k=1:size(static_row,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_row(k,2) , static_row(k,4)+0.5 , static_row(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0 0.8 0 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 0 1 0 ] );
    end
    arrays = 0.0;
    for k=1:size(static_row,1)
        arrays = arrays + static_row(k,3);
    end
    arrays/size(static_row,1)

    % Plot the pc in BLUE
    for k=1:size(static_column,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_column(k,2) , static_column(k,4)+0.5 , static_column(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0 0 0.8 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 0 0 1 ] );
    end
    arrays = 0.0;
    for k=1:size(static_column,1)
        arrays = arrays + static_column(k,3);
    end
    arrays/size(static_column,1)


    % Plot the pc in BLUE
    for k=1:size(static_split, 1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_split(k,2) , static_split(k,4)+0.5 , static_split(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0.6 0.6 0.0 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 1 1 0 ] );
    end
    arrays = 0.0;
    for k=1:size(static_split,1)
        arrays = arrays + static_split(k,3);
    end
    arrays/size(static_split,1)

    % Plot the unload
    for k=1:size(static_unload,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_unload(k,2) , static_unload(k,4)+0.5 , static_unload(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0.0 0.6 0.6 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 0 1 1 ] );
    end

    % Plot the load
    for k=1:size(static_load,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_load(k,2) ,         static_load(k,4)+0.5 , static_load(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0.6 0.0 0.6 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 1 0 1 ] );
    end

    %Plot the ghost in black
    for k=1:size(static_ghost,1)
        rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_ghost(k,2) , static_ghost(k,4)+0.5 , static_ghost(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
    'EdgeColor' , [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 0 0 0 ] );
    end

    hold off;
    xlabel('time (ms)');
    ylabel('block ID');
    set(gca,'YTick',0:8:128)
    title('Task plot for BH with simulated cudaMemcpy');
    axis([ 0 , ms_max , 0.5 , max(static(:,4))+1.5 ]);


    % Print this plot
    set( gcf , 'PaperSize' , 2.3*[ 30 4 ] );
    set( gcf , 'PaperPosition' , 2.3*[ 0.25 0.25 20 4 ] );
    %saveas(gcf, '/home/hudson/ug/d74ksy/PhD/BHTimers/tasks.eps', 'epsc');
    print(gcf, '/home/hudson/ug/d74ksy/PhD/BHTimers/tasks.eps', '-depsc' );
```

I tried using both saveas and print but I get purple text either way.
This is the output from the plot with the weird colours.
[output.eps](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5095155/one_queue_memcpy.eps)
I'm using MATLAB R2014a on linux remotely.

Anyone got any ideas why this would happen - do I need to set text colour (though that wouldn't explain why the rectangles drawn in:

```
    rectangle( 'Position' , [ static_ghost(k,2) , static_ghost(k,4)+0.5 , static_ghost(k,3) , 1 ] , ...
'EdgeColor' , [ 0.0 0.0 0.0 ] , 'LineWidth' , 1 , 'FaceColor' , [ 0 0 0 ] );
```

are also purple

Comment: questions like this are hardly answerable without runnable code to reproduce the problem. Please provide your data or even better, please reduce your code to the ***REALLY*** necessary part with exemplified data.

Comment: Reducing the code isn't really an option since (as I say in the answer below) the seemingly way to fix it was simply to move code around so the black cells are drawn first - why that happens is unclear. I could provide data potentially but I was unsure where to upload it to.

Answer (score 0):

Answer/workaround:
Moving the xlabel/ylabel/set/title/axis commands to before hold on; line and moving the section that draws the black boxes to be the first boxes drawn fixed the issue.